# Is it possible to get a rapid anti-gen Covid test at Mexico City International Airport

Tags: covid-19, mexico, mexico-city, mex

Is it possible to get a rapid anti-gen Covid test at Mexico City International Airport?

If so:

- Where is the test center located in the airport?
- Is it open 24/7?
- Do they provide a certificate that is valid for entry in the US (I am a US citizen with proof of vaccination)
- Is an appointment required?

If not:

- Does anyone know of a test location near the airport?

UPDATE: We stayed in the Courtyard Marriott hotel at the airport the night before our early morning flight. There was a Covid testing center right in the ground floor of the hotel. It was around 700 MXN (~ US$35) for a quick test (which provides the certificate acceptable for airlines to the US). No appointment needed. There were other on-the-spot test centers in the airport, probably cheaper.

Comment: Just traveled today (13 May 2022). There are two testing sites outside T2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://cms.volaris.com/en/travel-info/covid-19-testing-for-passengers/:

- Two locations at Terminal 1: Entrance 5 and the Volaris office at Annex 1
- 24/7
- valid for the US.
- $550 MXN

I believe no need for appointment. Maybe other airlines have other locations as well. I saw the location at Terminal 1 when I went there around New Year Eve, the queue seemed quite small but it's likely a good idea to arrive a bit earlier in case the queue long.

---

FYI, from [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/169924/1810), which quotes CDC:

> > The 1-day period [for COVID-19 testing when flying to the US] is 1 day before the flight’s departure. The Order uses a 1-day time frame instead of 24 hours to provide more flexibility to the air passenger and aircraft operator. By using a 1-day window, test acceptability does not depend on the time of the flight or the time of day that the test sample was taken.
>
> I'd advise to do the test within [24]h if possible or if not call the airline while recording the call, because some airline employees, such as some Qatar Airways employees I've encountered, can't read properly and mistakenly think [1 day = 24h], or may have their own policies.

but Mexican airlines should 100% understand the CDC 1-day guideline.

Comment: Thank you!  Particularly the observation that you saw it with your own eyes (the information on websites is not always accurate) and that the queue was shortish. We will arrive the evening before and stay in the airport hotel, so that should give us plenty of time.

Comment: @BrunoRijsman sounds good, note that you could even do the test the evening before. It only has to be done the same day or the day before.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Be careful with doing it the day before. It is usually required to been tested max 24 hours before ARRIVAL at destination. Not your DEPARTURE, so factor in your travel duration.

Comment: When we left Cancun, @Tonny, we had ours done at the hotel in the morning the day before departure. Our flights out were close to noon. YMMV.

Comment: Also, Just because the site was open at the airport on New Years Eve doesn't mean it's still open today, @BrunoRijsman. Just be prepared...

Comment: @FreeMan Last time I traveled requiring a PCR test they compared the time of publication of the test-result (which was 3 hours after taking the actual test) and compared that against expected arrival time. Tested at 8:00 AM, got result at 11:00 AM. Arrival (overnight ferry) was 11:30 AM next morning. They refused me boarding the ferry. I had to point out that due to 1 hour timezone difference, 11:30 arrival was actually 10:30 AM local time, so 23:30 hours after the test and not 24:30.

Comment: Yikes! When we left Cancun, the security person glanced at the emailed results so quickly I'm 99.999% sure that all she could have seen was "Negative". I don't recall the time details of our flights/test results as well as you do yours.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt The US Department of State website (https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/traveladvisories/ea/requirements-for-air-travelers-to-the-us.html) says "[you are] required to show documentation of a negative viral test result taken within one day of the flight’s *DEPARTURE* to the United States before boarding."

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt The FAQ on the same website has a question "What does it mean to test one day before departure" and the answer is "The test must be administered no more than one calendar day before the date of the international flight to the United States. So, if a traveler is departing for the United States at 10 PM on January 19, they would have to present a negative test result for a test that was taken any time after 12:01 AM on January 18."

Comment: @freeman Different countries have different rules for what kind of test (anti-gen or PCR) and exact timing (how many days and relative to arrival or departure). For the USA, my understanding is that rapid anti-gen is allowed and it has to be maximum one day before departure (the term day is purposely chosen and does not mean 24 hours, as clarified in the FAQ on the US state department website quoted in an earlier comment)

Comment: @BrunoRijsman correct, answer edited.

Comment: @Tonny true for some countries but not for the US. Dumb airline employees or airlines can be confused though.

Comment: @Tonny So true. I was once almost refused boarding a flight during the height of Covid when I wanted to fly to Amsterdam using a Belgium passport (at the time most countries only allowed citizens and permanent residents to enter, but the EU allowed all citizens from any EU country). The USA-based (Houston) gate agent did not know the rules or even what the EU was (she insisted I needed an "Amsterdam passport to fly to Amsterdam").

Comment: For what it's worth: When I left PVR, I paid 450 MXN for a rapid test at the airport.  If I had left San Blas an hour earlier, I could have got it in the city for 45 MXN.

Comment: @BrunoRijsman Americans and geography... My personal favorite I heard in Paris (the Texas town): "Europe? Isn't that the capital of France?"

Comment: @Tonny "Paris, Texas".... now there's a classic movie https://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/paris_texas